# How do I select a UITableViewCell by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have created a `UITableView` and would like a specific `UITableViewCell` to appear selected (blue) when the view is loaded.

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295297/uitableviewcell-set-selected-initially/25128427#25128427

Answer (score 41):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // assuming you had the table view wired to IBOutlet myTableView
    // and that you wanted to select the first item in the first section
    [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                             animated:NO 
                       scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

I'm using this technique to select one of two `UITableViewCells` so the users knows which cell a `UIDatePicker` below the table view it will effect. This technique is used by Apple in the calendar app when you create a new event and set the dates.

Comment: 1. this does not work for me. 2. Apple says you should use checkmark to indicate an item's selection state.

Answer (score 6):

Be judicious using this method, as selecting the row in this way is something [Apple suggests against](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW10) doing to show a "chosen" state.

Instead, consider setting the cell's `accessoryType` property to something like  `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the UI Apple use when you add/edit an event in the Calendar application and set a start and end date/time.  I saw comments about the checkmark rule elsewhere, but am uncertain whether it would apply in this case (the table is used to layout components rather than present a list of data).

Comment: That's an interesting point. In this case, they don't need to have a subview for each the Starts and Ends since they are both representing the same kind of data, modified by the same kind of UIPickerView. So that would represent a judicious use. They are likely using UITableView's selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: method... see http://tinyurl.com/yd9zs65

Answer (score 3):

You should put it in `viewWillAppear`.

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
                         animated:NO 
                   scrollPosition:0];
```

If you try to select it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, then it will not take the required style.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely watch out.  I'm sure you have a good reason, but look closely at the Human Interface Guidelines document Apple provides.  Apps get rejected for not unselecting table rows.  I'd encourage you to find the appropriate section of the HIG and see Apple offers any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to select cell by default in table view, `indexPath` can be vary according to your need

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [theTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITableViewCell method

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Info [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setSelected:animated).

Comment: Maybe following method suits better? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setHighlighted:animated:

Comment: which method?  the link doesnt go to any particular method

Comment: O i f ound it, that one highlights it and does not select it, I guess if thats all the asker wants then sure thats more suitable

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you're not in a `UIViewController`, you have no `viewWillAppear`, and sometimes, you created your `UITableView` programmatically.

The easy solution is to implement this `delegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        cell.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

It's does not work in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because the cell is not yet displayed. and the `setSelected` method is called just when this one is displayed.