# UITable Cell not selectable where there is a UITextView in the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've added a `UITextView` to my cell. If the userclicks on the cell where the `UITextView` then then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called unless they click the area where the `UITextView` is not covering. Is there a work around or what is it I have done wrong?

```
UITextView *txtview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 1, 250, 34)];//init and create the UIWebView
txtview.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
//txtview.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[txtview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[txtview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
txtview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtview.scrollEnabled = NO;

[txtview setOpaque:NO];
//[txtview setDelegate:self];
txtview.editable = NO;
txtview.text = aBlogRss.title;
[txtview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11,-8,0,0)];
//[txtview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
[cell addSubview:txtview];
[txtview release];
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the solution is actually

```
txtView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This will pass touches to the parent view.. or in this case the `UITableViewCell`. If you are doing this in multiple places it would be a good idea to subclass `UITAbleViewCell`.

Alternatively, you could make your class a UITextViewDelegate, set your txtView.delegate to self, and implement

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` ,

and then select the proper `UITableViewCell` through `self.tableview`.. But that would be nothing short of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your `UITextView` in `viewDidLoad:` and only keep `[cell addSubview:txtview];` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Alternatively, you can use: `[cell setAccessoryView: txtView];`

Another thing, how are you creating your cell?

Answer (score 0):

Is the cell used once or potentially unlimited number of times? If once, then you can use

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

and manually insert the indexPath since you know where it lies.

If the cell is to be re-used, try setting the "tag" property of the textfield with the row, then when the touch is detected by the UITextView, use one of its delegate methods to call the above UITableView method, providing an NSIndexPath derived from the UITextView's tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an UITapGestureRecognizer to the cells.
2. Write a gesture handling code like below.

   ```
   - (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
   {
       [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:
        [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.view]
                                   animated:NO
                             scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   }
   ```
3. Connect them.

You would obtain both selectable UITextView and selectable UITextViewCell.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it makes sense that the row does not get selected as there is a `textView` over it. Here are a couple of ways of going about this.

1. You can make the `textView` frame such that you provide room for selecting the row.
2. You can set each textView (for each row) as a property and find out which `textView` was selected. Based on that you can call the `textViewDidBeginEditing` method and programmatically make that row selectable.

   ```
   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   ```

   References: [How do I select a UITableViewCell by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323474/how-do-i-select-a-uitableviewcell-by-default)

   [Select tableview row programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically)

---

**Note:** You will have to logically link each `textView` with the it's corresponding `cellIndexPath`.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
txtView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

That should do it.