# detecting the selected Map Annotation Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i have a map and multiple annotations are dropped at. when i select an annotation, and i tap the disclosure button a new view appears (DetailViewController) that contains a table view.
What do i want is, when the DetailViewController opens, directly the description of the selected annotation become selected.

[image: this is the map and the annotations, when i tab the appeared the disclosure button image 2 appears and i want the description of the selected annotation become selected]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for detecting when MKAnnotation is selected in MKMapView

```
@interface ClassVC ()
{
    int notationTag;
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    notationTag = 0; //initialisation of variable
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mallicon.png"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);
            //pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            pinView.tag = notationTag;
        } else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        notationTag++;
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

then in calloutAccessoryControlTapped.,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control 
{
    ContactDetails *contact=[[ContactDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactDetails" bundle:nil];
    contact.name1Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",view.tag];
}
```

in the next view add this line of code

```
NSIndexPath *index =[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[name1Str intValue]];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

**In my case I used below code to reload you can try that too**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = view.annotation.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"======Tag====%ld", (long)view.tag);
    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[view tag] inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:rowToReload atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Good answer it saves my time     pinView.tag = i; this code was awesome

Answer (score 0):

use the delegate method `didSelectAnnotationView:` and push the detalViewController into your navigation controller

This will help.

Comment: i did that, but how to let the row that contains the details of the selected annotation become selected?!

Comment: you can do it by many ways.. All you need to do is set serial numbers to every annotations and pass that serial no to the detailViewController.

For setting a row selected, following link will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323474/how-do-i-select-a-uitableviewcell-by-default

Comment: yes dude, i gave each pin a serial number already. but how to detect with one i have selected??

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
      AnnotationView *annotation = (AnnotationView *)mapView.annotation;
      NSInteger *yourIndex = annotation.myindex;
}
```

and push your navigation controller

Comment: i did that, but how to let the row that contains the details of the selected annotation become selected?!